# Download exact replica of source to destination, by deleting user created local files in destination

Tags: jfrog-cli

I have artifactory source folder with the following contents:
a->a1.txt, a2.txt
b->b1.txt, b3.txt

In the local directory, I have extra files in Local machine:
a->a1.txt, a2.txt, a3.txt
b->b1.txt, b2.txt, b3.txt

When I download files from artifactory using jfrog-cli, I need to have a exact replica of Artifactory source by deleting the user defined files of a3.txt & b3.txt

Final Output:
a->a1.txt, a2.txt
b->b1.txt, b3.txt

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no option to do that using the JFrog CLI. Really the only option you have right now is to write a script that removes all files and downloads the content from JFrog Artifactory after that.

If you want, you can create a new GitHub issue for the JFrog team [here](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go) so they can evaluate the request.